# IIS, How To Open in Chrome? (if i open web page in chrome then automatically open internet explorer blowser)

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, iis

I currently developing a ASP.NET web application.

The problem is that I open this web application in chrome,
then chrome browser is automatically closed and internet explorer browser is opened.

I don't know why chrome web browser is closed.
Is problem in IIS setting? or in Asp.NET code?

Comment: Can you reproduce this with a simple HTML page (like `index.html`)? IIS/ASP.NET as backend technologies often have no control on browser behaviors, so it sounds like some JavaScript tricks or browser extension magic. Without access to the actual source code of your web application or your machine, it is impossible for anyone to help over the internet.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It turned out that the cause was due to company's policy. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

In VS2022, see the below screenshot to open IIS in chrome
[image]

1. Click on Local IIS dropdown
2. Go to Web Browser -> Click on Google Chrome

This will reflect Local IIS(Google Chrome)